# Positioning Row widgets in a Container: Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to position the **+** and **-** icons inside the '**ADD**' Container at the extreme right and left ends of the container respectively. Also, I want to place the '**LEFT**' Container to the Top left side of the image.

I tried using `Positioned.fill` and `Align` Widget in the LEFT container but it doesn't seem to work.

```
class ImageStack extends StatelessWidget {
  const ImageStack({
    Key key,
    @required this.size,
    @required this.restaurantItems,
    @required this.cart,
    @required this.widget,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Size size;
  final RestaurantItems restaurantItems;
  final Cart cart;
  final RestaurantItemList widget;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          height: size.width * 0.30,
          width: size.width * 0.30,
        ),
        ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          child: Image.network(
            restaurantItems.imageUrl,
            height: size.width * 0.28,
            width: size.width * 0.28,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        Positioned.fill(
          bottom: 0.0,
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 19, top: 6, right: 15, bottom: 6),
                child: InkWell(
                  splashColor: Colors.white,
                  onTap: () async {
                    
                    await cart.addItemCart(
                        widget.restaurant.id,
                        restaurantItems.id,
                        restaurantItems.price,
                        restaurantItems.quantity,
                        context);
                  
                  },
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    mainAxisAlignment:
                        MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: [
                      Icon(
                        Icons.remove,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        size: 17,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        // ''
                        'ADD',
                        // : '${restaurantItems[i].quantity}',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 16),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding:
                            const EdgeInsets.only(right: 3),
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.add,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          size: 17,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned.fill(
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 4),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.teal[900],
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                child: Text(
                  '${restaurantItems.quantity} LEFT',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Raleway',
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                      fontSize: 15),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks for your Time and Support.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
return Stack(
  children: [
    Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      height: size.width * 0.30,
      width: size.width * 0.30,
    ),
    ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
      child: Image.network(
        restaurantItems.imageUrl,
        height: size.width * 0.28,
        width: size.width * 0.28,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    ),
    Positioned.fill(
      bottom: 0.0,
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
            color: Colors.green,
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 6, bottom: 6),
            child: InkWell(
              splashColor: Colors.white,
              onTap: () async {
                
                await cart.addItemCart(
                    widget.restaurant.id,
                    restaurantItems.id,
                    restaurantItems.price,
                    restaurantItems.quantity,
                    context);
              
              },
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment:
                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Icon(
                    Icons.remove,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    size: 17,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    // ''
                    'ADD',
                    // : '${restaurantItems[i].quantity}',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 16),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding:
                        const EdgeInsets.only(right: 3),
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.add,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      size: 17,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Positioned(
      top: 0.0,
      left: 0.0,
      child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 4),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.teal[900],
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
            child: Text(
              '${restaurantItems.quantity} LEFT',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Raleway',
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                  fontSize: 15),
            ),
          ),
        ),
    )
  ],
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an `Expanded` widget into the Row containing `+` `Add` `-` and set the `Text('Add')` as the child of the `Expanded` this will make the Text Fill the area remaining after the `+` and `-` elements have been placed.

```
Expanded(child:Text(
                        // ''
                        'ADD',
                        // : '${restaurantItems[i].quantity}',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 16),
                      )),
```

Is there any reason you're using `Positioned.fill`? As you are not filling the display area with this element a regular `Positioned` widget with the `Top` and `Left` set to 0 should give you the desired result.

Comment: So I should add 2 Expanded Widgets? One in Row and the other in Text?

Comment: I tried using Expanded in the Text Widget, but it only expands space between the '+' icon and 'ADD'

Comment: No just one in the row, answer updated with code sample, you cannot place a child in a Text widget and Expanded must be used in a Flex.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, maybe the issue is arising from MainAxisSize and CrossAxisAlignment 
set mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.max and set CrossAxisAlignment to CrossAxisAlignment.Stretch.

Comment: Adding Expanded alone won't fix the issue. The Widget hierarchy displayed above complex, simplify it and you should be able to get the desired result. If all else fails and you need this done do consider  CustomMultiChildLayout => https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomMultiChildLayout-class.html

All the best hope you find a solution